# Append numeric value to input name attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to add _1, _2 etc to the end of my input elements in a dynamic form. The user can add as many as they want I wrote this method but it seems to throw errors saying the "dName is undefined"

```
$j("#addBranch").click(
                    function()
                        {
                            //see withDataAndEvents, copies events with bool in clone method
                            $j('.branchOffice').first().clone(true).appendTo('#branchOffice');
                            $j('.branchOffice').last().children().attr('name',function()
                            {
                                var dName = $j(this.name).attr('name');
                                    return dName.substring(0, dName.length-1) + ($j('.branchOffice').size() + 1)
                                });    
                        }
                    );
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="leftPane">
        <label for="company_name">Company Name</label>
        <input class="req"  type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" />
        <label for="branch_office">Home Office</label>
        <input class="req" type="text" name="branch_office_1" id="branch_office_1" />
        <label for="branch_office_add1_1">Address</label>
        <input class="req" type="text" name="branch_office_add1_1" id="branch_office_add1_1" />
        <label for="branch_office_add2_1">Address 2</label>
        <input type="text" name="branch_office_add2_1" id="branch_office_add2_1" />
        <label for="branch_office_city_1">City</label>
        <input class="req" type="text" name="branch_office_city_1" id="branch_office_city_1" />
        <label for="branch_office_state_1">State</label>
        <select id="branch_office_state_1" name="branch_office_state_1">
            <?php echo $formHelper->stateList; ?>
        </select>
        <label class="naked" for="branch_office_zip_1">Zip</label>
        <input class="req zip"  type="text" name="branch_office_zip_1" id="branch_office_zip_1" />
    </div>
    <div class="rightPane" id="branchOffice">
        <div class="branchOffice">
            <label for="branch_office_2">Branch Office</label>
            <input class="req" type="text" name="branch_office_2" id="branch_office_2" />
            <label for="branch_office_add1_2">Address</label>
            <input class="req" type="text" name="branch_office_add1_2" id="branch_office_add1_2" />
            <label for="branch_office_add2_2">Address 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="branch_office_add2_2" id="branch_office_add2_2" />
            <label for="branch_office_city_2">City</label>
            <input class="req" type="text" name="branch_office_city_2" id="branch_office_city_2" />
            <label for="branch_office_state_2">State</label>
            <select id="branch_office_state_2" name="branch_office_state_2">
                <?php echo $formHelper->stateList; ?>
            </select>
            <label for="branch_office_zip_2">Zip</label>
            <input class="req zip"  type="text" name="branch_office_zip_2" id="branch_office_zip_2" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <small class="red">If more than one branch office, please</small><a class="addMore" title="Add Branch" id="addBranch">Add More</a>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? I gave it a go, but it's hard to be sure without knowing the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dName = $j(this).attr('name');
```

or, now that i look again, `$j(this)` referes to `.branhOffice` and not `#addBranch`.

maybe set a val;

```
var addBranch = $(this);
```

then your other selects then

```
var dName = $(addBranch).attr('name');
```

Comment: I should have explained more thoroughly, #addBranch is a button, .branchOffice is a div class of the office element that I want to duplicate and #branchOffice is the container (I should have named it something a bit more helpful like "#branchesContainer"